# Azure Function and CRON again

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I want to call every day at 23:00.

I try the following:

```
        [TimerTrigger("0 23 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
```

but I get an error:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'FunctionAppCallEfsFuelCards.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions:
>   The schedule expression '0 23 * * *' was not recognized as a valid
>   cron expression or timespan string.

what is wrong?

Comment: Seems like you're missing a parameter (supposed to be `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}`)

Comment: should be [TimerTrigger("0 0 23 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,

Answer (score 2):

Just summarized as an answer, as @DavidMakogon said in comment, the correct crontab expression should be `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}` in Timer Trigger of Azure Functions.

The section [`NCRONTAB expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#ncrontab-expressions) of the offical document [`Timer trigger for Azure Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) explains it, as the figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main format used for the scheduled WebJob

- The cron expression is composed of 6 fields:  {second} {minute}
  {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}.
- The supported operators are: , - * /
- Each field can have a specific    value (1), a range (1-10), a set of
  values (1,2,3), all values (), an    interval value (/2 ==
  0,2,4,6,...) or a mix of these (1,5-10).
- Each value represents a point in time, for example: "5 * * * * *" -
  means on the 5th second of every minutes according to above rules
  your cron expression will leads to this error

  use **[TimerTrigger("0 0 23 * * ? *")]TimerInfo myTimer,**

also you can validate your cron expression using [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

Comment: I have tried to run a timertrigger with 7 characters and each time it threw an error.  It seems it won't allow for more than 6.  Any idea why?